# How to change the display text of a link in Youtube comment?

Tags: youtube

I want the following link to appear like this: [w3schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not possible**; YouTube comments only support very basic formatting, as described e.g. [here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6000964) or in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=al2AN2pbnu8):

> ### Add formatting to comments
>
> #### Add style to your comment
>
> You can use rich text to format your comment with common special tags, such as:
>
> - `*bold text*` → **bold**
> - `_italicized text_` → *italics*
> - `-strikethrough text-` → <s>strikethrough</s>
>
> #### Add links to your comment
>
> If you add a URL to your comment, it will show as a hyperlink.

The hyperlink is made clickable, but you can't choose the title of the link.

Answer (score 1):

Up to my knowledge it is not possible, although there is at least [one example](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/144170/how-did-this-person-add-a-hyperlink-in-the-youtube-comments) of people doing it.

Comment: An other example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5Z91bWyvzo&lc=UgimMmPlnIPSfHgCoAEC&ab_channel=NomadicAssassin1

Both examples are from ~2014. Maybe this is an old functionality, which is not possible any more....