# How did this person add a hyperlink in the YouTube comments?

Tags: youtube, links

I found this comment from over 6 years ago. It has a hyperlink to a YouTube video, not a link, but a hyperlink. How was/is this done?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbDHfUc_fMI&lc=UggS2CQUfc2M4XgCoAEC

Answer (score 0):

So I've found myself here because I was trying to post a link to one of my own comments inside another comment I made down further but what would happen is when trying to then click that link to a previous comment, my browser would show when hovered over that the link had cut off the section that refers to the comment.

So as a demo, if I right-clicked and use the 'copy link' feature, I paste the link into the address field first (otherwise it's posts it as shortened-text hyperlink), then I grab the 'shortened link' (by using the Share feature on the video and replace the standard link section (everything before `lc=`)

Standard comment link: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=...&lc=...`
Shortened comment link that will then link correctly in other comments: `https://youtu.be/...&lc=...`

*Browser used is Safari Version 13.1.2 (13609.3.5.1.5) on macOS 10.13.6 High Sierra*

Answer (score 0):

It seems hyperlinks in YouTube comments were supported at some time but YouTube removed that feature. I guess for security reasons because it makes it easier for scammer to make you click on one of their links (that's just an assumption though).

Answer (score -1):

That link is directed to a video and highlights a comment...

This link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bbDHfUc_fMI&lc=UggS2CQUfc2M4XgCoAEC is normal until the &lc=UggS2CQUfc2M4XgCoAEC

the &lc= is basically what dictates that a comment will be highlighted

People can get to a link like that by notifications that highlight there own comment. What probably happened was the person who shared that link, shared it when they were looking at there own comment.

Comment: OP is talking about the comment that is highlighted not about the link you are talking about. Please check the top comment under that video. It has a link that is not showing something like [https://www.google.com](https://www.google.com) but instead it shows a "Hyperlink" like this -> [Google](https://www.google.com)